# The join operation was not successful

Tags: windows

When attempting to connect to domain controller in Windows Server 2019 the following error comes up "The join operation was not successful. This could be because existing computer account having name was previously created using different set of credentials."

I have attempted renaming the computer and connecting and also tried deleting it from the domain controller to be able to add it back but both did not resolve the issue. Any suggestions workarounds are appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Did You restart the computer after renaming it?

Comment: yes we did of course to validate if we still can make it work but no success

Comment: remove the computer from the server-side

Comment: already tried that :(

Comment: when you removed the computer from the server-side, then did you join from the computer side?

Comment: yes correct we did

Answer (score 0):

When entering your credentials, enter them as follows:

domain\adminaccount.

and of course, you will replaced "domain" with your domain name
and then \ and then your admin account

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if computer account already exists on the domain.
2. If it already exists, delete it and try to join machine to the domain.
3. If it doesn’t exist. Create it, than remove (do this on the domain server) and then try to join the domain again (from the client machine).

Answer (score 0):

Try to join the computer to the domain under a domain user account that is a member of Domain Admins group. We had the same case and it helped